# Automatically update EF CORE dbcontext quarterly

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

In my web project, I use EF CORE Power Tools to create the initial dbcontext in a data model project.  The tools extract tables and views from several sql servers. Several of the SQL tables are created quarterly and the web project needs to connect to those tables when new quarter starts.  How can I do this automatically so that the dbContext stay fresh?  Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to use them for reporting?

Comment: no. this is just for CRUD operation